# Show Directions between 2 points on click event with Google Maps Api

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need help with the Google Maps API and the direction Services

**My Goal:**
To create a map centred on my primary address.
The create 3x overlay buttons to represent nearby towns.
Once a user clicks on either of the buttons, the directions/route between the selected town and my primary address will display.
A fourth button will enable a user to reset the map, centre it and remove the directions.

**Achieved thus far**

- Create a map and centre it on my primary location
- Create the overlay buttons for the 3x towns, though the click event doesn't work
- Create the 4th button to centre the map
- Create the rout between one of the towns and my primary address

**Need help with**
To only show the route when the button is clicked.
At the moment the route display from the get go.
To make the rout disappear when the reset button is clicked.
To change the route if another town button is clicked.

**Resources**

- Image: [image: Image showing what I'm hoping to achieve.]
- [Link my dev site:](http://pw.thissideupmedia.com/) (map at the bottom)
- [Link to my fiddle, which is working.](https://jsfiddle.net/thissideupmedia/rf314x97/14/)

**code snippet:**

```js
const paarl = {
  lat: -33.727494,
  lng: 18.9261117
}

function PaarlControl(controlDiv, map) {
  const controlUI = document.createElement("div");
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(237,24,72,0.6)";
  controlUI.style.border = "2px solid #ed1848";
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = "3px 3px 0 0";
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
  controlUI.style.cursor = "pointer";
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = "22px";
  controlUI.style.textAlign = "center";
  controlUI.title = "Click for directions from Paarl";
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  const controlText = document.createElement("div");
  controlText.style.color = "#fff";
  controlText.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
  controlText.style.fontSize = "16px";
  controlText.style.lineHeight = "24px";
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
  controlText.style.paddingRight = "5px";
  controlText.innerHTML = "Paarl<br>42km<br><small>click for directions to Pink Valley</small>";
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
    map.setCenter(paarl);
  });
}

// ==================
// LABEL CAPE TOWN
// ==================
const capetownint = {
  lat: -33.971463,
  lng: 18.5998911
}

function CapetownintControl(controlDiv, map) {
  const controlUI = document.createElement("div");
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(237,24,72,0.6)";
  controlUI.style.border = "2px solid #ed1848";
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = "3px 3px 0 0";
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
  controlUI.style.cursor = "pointer";
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = "22px";
  controlUI.style.textAlign = "center";
  controlUI.title = "Click for directions from Cape Town International";
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  const controlText = document.createElement("div");
  controlText.style.color = "#fff";
  controlText.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
  controlText.style.fontSize = "16px";
  controlText.style.lineHeight = "24px";
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
  controlText.style.paddingRight = "5px";
  controlText.innerHTML = "Cape Town International<br>32km<br><small>click for directions to Pink Valley</small>";
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
    map.setCenter(capetownint);
  });
}

// ==================
// LABEL STELLENBOSCH
// ==================
const stellenbosch = {
  lat: -33.9466715,
  lng: 18.774375
}

function StellenboschControl(controlDiv, map) {
  const controlUI = document.createElement("div");
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(237,24,72,0.6)";
  controlUI.style.border = "2px solid #ed1848";
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = "3px 3px 0 0";
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
  controlUI.style.cursor = "pointer";
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = "22px";
  controlUI.style.textAlign = "center";
  controlUI.title = "Click for directions from Stellenbosch";
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  const controlText = document.createElement("div");
  controlText.style.color = "#fff";
  controlText.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
  controlText.style.fontSize = "16px";
  controlText.style.lineHeight = "24px";
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
  controlText.style.paddingRight = "5px";
  controlText.innerHTML = "STELLENBOSCH<br>13km<br><small>click for directions to Pink Valley</small>";
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
  controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {});
}

// ==================
// CENTER
// ==================
// let map;
const pinkvalley = {
  lat: -34.030553,
  lng: 18.829326
}

function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {
  const controlUI = document.createElement("div");
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(237,24,72,0.6)";
  controlUI.style.border = "2px solid #ed1848";
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = "3px 3px 0 0";
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
  controlUI.style.cursor = "pointer";
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = "22px";
  controlUI.style.textAlign = "center";
  controlUI.title = "Click to recenter the map";
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  const controlText = document.createElement("div");
  controlText.style.color = "#fff";
  controlText.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
  controlText.style.fontSize = "16px";
  controlText.style.lineHeight = "38px";
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
  controlText.style.paddingRight = "5px";
  controlText.innerHTML = "Center Map on Pink Valley";
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
    map.setCenter(pinkvalley);
  });
}


function initMap() {

  var pinkvalley = {
    lat: -34.030553,
    lng: 18.829326
  }; // already set above
  var pointA = pinkvalley,
    pointB = stellenbosch,
    pointC = paarl,
    pointD = capetownint,

    myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: pinkvalley,
      mapTypeId: 'hybrid', // roadmap, sattelite, terrain, hybrid
      disableDefaultUI: true, // Disable all Controls
      zoomControl: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      caleControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      rotateControl: false,
      fullscreenControl: true,
      fullscreenControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
      }
    }



  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), myOptions),

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "point A",
      label: "A",
      map: map
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointB,
      title: "point B",
      label: "B",
      map: map
    }),

  markerC = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pointC,
    title: "Paarl",
    label: "PAARL",
    map: map
  });


  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointC);



  // DIR ENS


  const image =
    "http://pink-valley.local/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/assets/img/icon-90.png";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pinkvalley,
    map: map,
    icon: image,

  });


  const centerControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);

  const stellenboschControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  StellenboschControl(stellenboschControlDiv, map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(stellenboschControlDiv);

  const capetownintControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  CapetownintControl(capetownintControlDiv, map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(capetownintControlDiv);

  const paarlControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  PaarlControl(paarlControlDiv, map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(paarlControlDiv);


  // stellenboschControlDiv.addEventListener("click", () => {
  //   overlay.toggleDOM(map);
  // });



}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    avoidTolls: true,
    avoidHighways: false,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```

Comment: This is an update / better version of my original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242353/add-a-click-event-to-show-directions-with-google-map-api

Comment: If this question isn't valid anymore, then delete it please.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the directions from appearing on page load, remove the line of code that creates them (in the `initMap` function):

```
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointC);
```

To create directions on click of your various controls, call that function there instead:

```
// paarl
    controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
      map.setCenter(paarl);
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, paarl, pinkvalley);
    });
// capetown
    controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
      map.setCenter(capetownint);
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, capetownint, pinkvalley);
    });
// stellonbosch
    controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, stellenbosch, pinkvalley);
   });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ue1Lc87d/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
const paarl = {
  lat: -33.727494,
  lng: 18.9261117
}

function PaarlControl(controlDiv, map) {
  const controlUI = document.createElement("div");
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(237,24,72,0.6)";
  controlUI.style.border = "2px solid #ed1848";
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = "3px 3px 0 0";
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
  controlUI.style.cursor = "pointer";
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = "22px";
  controlUI.style.textAlign = "center";
  controlUI.title = "Click for directions from Paarl";
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  const controlText = document.createElement("div");
  controlText.style.color = "#fff";
  controlText.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
  controlText.style.fontSize = "16px";
  controlText.style.lineHeight = "24px";
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
  controlText.style.paddingRight = "5px";
  controlText.innerHTML = "Paarl<br>42km<br><small>click for directions to Pink Valley</small>";
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
    map.setCenter(paarl);
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, paarl, pinkvalley);
  });
}

// ==================
// LABEL CAPE TOWN
// ==================
const capetownint = {
  lat: -33.971463,
  lng: 18.5998911
}

function CapetownintControl(controlDiv, map) {
  const controlUI = document.createElement("div");
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(237,24,72,0.6)";
  controlUI.style.border = "2px solid #ed1848";
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = "3px 3px 0 0";
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
  controlUI.style.cursor = "pointer";
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = "22px";
  controlUI.style.textAlign = "center";
  controlUI.title = "Click for directions from Cape Town International";
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  const controlText = document.createElement("div");
  controlText.style.color = "#fff";
  controlText.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
  controlText.style.fontSize = "16px";
  controlText.style.lineHeight = "24px";
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
  controlText.style.paddingRight = "5px";
  controlText.innerHTML = "Cape Town International<br>32km<br><small>click for directions to Pink Valley</small>";
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
    map.setCenter(capetownint);
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, capetownint, pinkvalley);
  });
}

// ==================
// LABEL STELLENBOSCH
// ==================
const stellenbosch = {
  lat: -33.9466715,
  lng: 18.774375
}

function StellenboschControl(controlDiv, map) {
  const controlUI = document.createElement("div");
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(237,24,72,0.6)";
  controlUI.style.border = "2px solid #ed1848";
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = "3px 3px 0 0";
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
  controlUI.style.cursor = "pointer";
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = "22px";
  controlUI.style.textAlign = "center";
  controlUI.title = "Click for directions from Stellenbosch";
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  const controlText = document.createElement("div");
  controlText.style.color = "#fff";
  controlText.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
  controlText.style.fontSize = "16px";
  controlText.style.lineHeight = "24px";
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
  controlText.style.paddingRight = "5px";
  controlText.innerHTML = "STELLENBOSCH<br>13km<br><small>click for directions to Pink Valley</small>";
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
  controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, stellenbosch, pinkvalley);
  });
}

// ==================
// CENTER
// ==================
// let map;
const pinkvalley = {
  lat: -34.030553,
  lng: 18.829326
}

function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {
  const controlUI = document.createElement("div");
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(237,24,72,0.6)";
  controlUI.style.border = "2px solid #ed1848";
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = "3px 3px 0 0";
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
  controlUI.style.cursor = "pointer";
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = "22px";
  controlUI.style.textAlign = "center";
  controlUI.title = "Click to recenter the map";
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  const controlText = document.createElement("div");
  controlText.style.color = "#fff";
  controlText.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
  controlText.style.fontSize = "16px";
  controlText.style.lineHeight = "38px";
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
  controlText.style.paddingRight = "5px";
  controlText.innerHTML = "Center Map on Pink Valley";
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
    map.setCenter(pinkvalley);
  });
}

function initMap() {
  var pinkvalley = {
    lat: -34.030553,
    lng: 18.829326
  }; // already set above
  var pointA = pinkvalley,
    pointB = stellenbosch,
    pointC = paarl,
    pointD = capetownint,

    myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: pinkvalley,
      mapTypeId: 'hybrid', // roadmap, sattelite, terrain, hybrid
      disableDefaultUI: true, // Disable all Controls
      zoomControl: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      caleControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      rotateControl: false,
      fullscreenControl: true,
      fullscreenControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
      }
    }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), myOptions),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "point A",
      label: "A",
      map: map
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointB,
      title: "point B",
      label: "B",
      map: map
    }),

    markerC = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointC,
      title: "Paarl",
      label: "PAARL",
      map: map
    });

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  // DIR ENS
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pinkvalley,
    map: map,
  });

  const centerControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);

  const stellenboschControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  StellenboschControl(stellenboschControlDiv, map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(stellenboschControlDiv);

  const capetownintControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  CapetownintControl(capetownintControlDiv, map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(capetownintControlDiv);

  const paarlControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  PaarlControl(paarlControlDiv, map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(paarlControlDiv);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    avoidTolls: true,
    avoidHighways: false,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```